# Hadoop (2.6) input split location in resourcemanager web ui

Tags: hadoop

I want to check my map task locality or remotely, so after a job finished, I go to resource manager port 8088 to see the details.

But when I selected each map task, I just see the location where map task run, and can not find the location of input split that map task used.

So could anyone point out how to find this information to check the localily of map tasks in hadoop 2.6

Answer (score 1):

You can check that out in the counters, you have 3 counters for that:

- data-local map tasks (data was on local node)
- rack-local map tasks (data was on the same rack)
- other local map tasks (data had to be shipped over from a different rack)

Example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support ! Based on your example , I understand that your job launched 23 tasks in which 12 tasks are local. Is it right? And what is the meaning of value in Map, Reduce column, why are they zero? If they get a positive value so what does it mean?

Comment: The zeros are there due to the counter/RM UI, those counters are job level counters. And you understand correctly - 12 were started with local data, 4 on the same rack as the data, and 7 on different racks.